# How to enable .net framework after install the .net framework?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, wine, dotnet

I am trying to install one program named TecDoc Catalog.
I am using Lubuntu 17.10 whit installed 32 bit Wine, winetricks and configured  wineprefix(installed dotnet452).

When i try to run the Install.exe whit Wine it shows this error:

> This application could not be started. You must enable the .NET
>   Framework from Windows Features dialog box (from Control Panel, choose
>   Programs, Turn Windows features on or off).
>
> Do you want to view information about this issue?

If i click "yes" it leads me here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/p/install_dotnet_control_panel/

In terminal the error looks like this:

```
fixme:ntdll:WinSqmIsOptedIn (): stub
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\fondue.exe"
```

I have installed .net framework(dotnet452),  i'm asking how to enable it?
Please tell me how to do it by terminal.

Thanks!

tip: Before install dotnet452 the error was "This app require installed .net framework..." Now i need to enable it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error with a different application. The error seems to be that .NET 2.0 isn't installed, though the message doesn't actually say that. `winetricks dotnet20` solved the issue for me (install winetricks first with `sudo apt install winetricks`. This was in addition to a newer version of .NET Framework that I already had installed - that wasn't enough.